# Docusign embedded signing accessCode XML

Tags: docusignapi

What elements need to be present for sending Rest API XML call for an accessCode on an envelope? Also, where does this element need to reside in the XML string? this is for an embedded signing of a PDF I am sending.

```
"<signers>" +
"<signer>" +
"<name>"joe"</name>" +
"<email>"joe@email.com"</email>" +
"<accessCode>"1234"</accessCode>" +
```

Answer (score 1):

The accesscode node should be defined within the signer block. Take a look at the POST {vx}/accounts/{accountid}/envelopes, v2-xml section of the create envelope XML sample at https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help.

Comment: This still did not work. Is there a setting in the Docusign sandbox that needs to be enabled for this feature to work?

Comment: I figured it out. The access code does not apply when using the email account for the sandbox. Need to use a different email and it works just fine. thanks for the help documentation, this will be very useful.

Comment: Ah, ok. There is an account setting called 'sender as a signer must authenticate'. You most likely want to turn this on, since when sender = signer you could get different behavior depending on your settings.

Comment: You can create additional users within your Sandbox account. You can set the additional users to not have administrative rights.